# Avoid repeating base_url in the config.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writing custom configs in my `config.php` file in codeigniter but from development to production,there is lots of work renaming my custom configs to reflect the new domain.

For instance

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/_init/';

$config['media_player_js']  = 'http://localhost/assets/';

$config['media_player_css'] = 'http://localhost/_init/';

$config['videos']   = 'http://localhost/_init/';

$config['audios']   = 'http://localhost/_init/';
```

I have had to repeat the base url four times.Is `$config['base_url']` variable available for use inside of the `config.php` file?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why are You defining base_url() in Your config file like that? base_url should contain the base path. I am giving the example which I use in my project:-

in Your config file define base_url like below:-

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";
```

then suppose You want to access `assets` folder. So You only need to write `base_url()."assets/"`. like this You can access any of Your folder from anywhere within the project.

**Note :- for production server also base_url() doesn't require any change.**

Comment: negetive point???!!! specify reason plz... because in this format I have completed almost 10 project in codeigniter....

Comment: The guy who have made negative comment plz otherwise I will ask to moderator of stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['base_url'] = '/_init/';
$config['media_player_js']  = '/assets/';
$config['media_player_css'] = '/_init/';
$config['videos']   = '/_init/';
$config['audios']   = '/_init/';
```

will let you use the same config on any domain.

Comment: Any ideas why this `$config['media_player_js'] = $config['base_url'] .'assets/custom.js';` and `echo $this->config->item('media_player_js'); ` works?And by the way your solution does not work.

Comment: Any idea why it shouldn't?

Comment: I guess its too early to start using `$config['base_url']` variable ;)

Comment: @user2420583 too early to use a previously defined variable? When it's time to use it then?

Comment: I almost forgot the config was a php file.My mindset of configs has always been fixated to xml.My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised this works

```
$config['media_player_js'] = $config['base_url'] .'assets/media_player.js';
```

and to use it

```
echo $this->config->item('media_player_js');
```

Comment: Please leave a comment.